# Is it bad to completely replace Hash with HashWithIndifferentAccess in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, activesupport

I find myself constantly running into bugs where I access Hashes with symbols instead of strings and vice versa. I would like to do:

```
require 'active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access'
Hash = HashWithIndifferentAccess
# (irb):xx: warning: already initialized constant Hash
```

This warning is because Hash is already defined, but I don't really care.

Sure, the performance might be slightly worse.

Sure, maybe some gem creates a hash with strings AND symbols and will break -- but how common is that?

Is this bad?  Anti-pattern? Will I regret doing this?  What are the downsides?  Any good/bad experiences doing this?

Comment: Why do you try to access Hashes with strings in first place? Symbols are the clear winners.

Comment: @ArslanAli In older versions of Ruby, symbols weren't garbage collected.  It would be easy to pollute the symbol table with lots of symbols when using JSON decode or similar where you don't have control over how many symbols get defined.

Comment: Would you want to read someone else's code where that has been done? This is equivalent to adding `alias :kat :cat` because one cannot spell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think `{}.class` is going to be after your kludge? Right, it will be `Hash`.

What do you think `Hash[:a, 'a']` will do? Right, `SystemStackError` for hopefully obvious reasons.

So yes, this is a bad idea, you will regret it, and an important downside is that it doesn't actually do what you think it will do.

Comment: Any ideas how to make Ruby Hash more user-friendly by default?  I really can't see a great reason for cases like ```Hash[:a, 'a', 'a', :a]```.

Comment: Um, don't think about it all? I've never actually had a symbol/string problem so I don't see much point to this. When you program in Ruby, program in Ruby, not something that mostly looks like Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The big downside is that you are making your Hash functions become O(n) instead of O(1). Comparing strings is much more demanding than comparing symbols so I'd say that would be a significant performance hit.

You shouldn't really be running into bugs when accessing Hashes with symbols since they are very similar to strings, maybe reading this article helps: [Differences between symbols and strings](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/)

Comment: Actually, as of Ruby v2.2.0, direct string access into a Hash will freeze the string, lowering the complexity and improving performance of string lookups: http://www.sitepoint.com/unraveling-string-key-performance-ruby-2-2/